# Symfony2 : how i get if variable post exist

Tags: php, symfony

I will try to verify if one variable POST exist but my function is not recognize.

```
$request = $this->get('request');

if($request->has('variable')){
// do something
}
```

But the function has is not implement into request but i have seen is implement into parameterBag.
So i don't know how use parameterBag.

I have try to search in google but all solution is to use

```
"$request->has('variable')"
or
$request->hasParameter('variable')
```

But has and hasParameter is not a function in request ...

Thanks for help,

regards,

Jérôme

Comment: The syntax is a bit strange: $request->request->has('xxx').  The second request is actually the parameter bag holding any posted data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`POST` variables are stored in `$request->request` (the naming is confusing). try this,

```
if ($request->request->has('variable')) {
    //do something
}
```

Keep in mind that each property of your Request [is a ParameterBag instance (or a sub-class of)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#accessing-request-data). The point here is to target the `request` property (which holds the POST data)

Comment: Yes its works thanks a lot for your answer :) its very confusing method ^^

Answer (score 0):

I may add that if you are expecting to do this in a Controller, you may not use the "request" service, but add the $request object as a parameter of your action (as it will be automatically replaced with the actual Request object).